# simple question about difference between array.item(n) and array[n]?

Tags: javascript

I have a question.
I was recently writing some javascript code in  dreamweaver and in it's code complete everytime i would deal with array of elements it will give me array.item(n) rather then array[n]

What is the difference between those two ?

Some example code:

```
function hideAllSubMenu(){
    var submenu = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++)
    {
        if(submenu.item(i).className == "submenu_wrap")
            submenu.item(i).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

However it can be writen in such maner as well

```
function hideAllSubMenu(){
    var submenu = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++)
    {
        if(submenu.[i].className == "submenu_wrap")
            submenu.[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

It is somewhat confusing for somebody like me who in his first steps on learning core javascript.
Can somebody explain to me what is a difference

Comment: To be technically correct, this isn't 'core' javascript. It is javascript + DOM :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *item* method is available on some node lists of the ***DOM***.
The [] is array accessor.

So you can use *item* when manipulating with DOM. But not on a normal array.
Generally I would suggest to always use [] as it is just works in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

i think you meant `submenu[i]` in the second example and item(n) and [n] are synonymous

Comment: I just want to know what is the difference (if any) between array.item(n) and array[n]

I never saw any JavaScript example using array.item(n) however firebug apparently has no problem compiling it.

Comment: 'synonymous' === 'no difference'

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there isn't anything built-in such as `Array.item` in Javascript.

document.getElementsByTagName returns a [`nodelist`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) object which looks and behaves like an array, but it isn't an Array. However, `nodelist[i]` and `nodelist.item(i)` are equivalent.

Comment: I never claimed there is something like that build in JavaScript.
Thats why i gave example to clarify about my question.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I was just clarifying that you can't use Array.item() in regular arrays.